# print_req_error: I/0 error

Tags: io

Every couple of days I get these errors that lockup the server.

```
[501.882940] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0

[504.338961] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0

[504.738984] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0

[509.250929] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0

[509.898921] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0

[510.334916] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0

[517.714867] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0

[520.118801] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0

[520.618864] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0

[521.047029] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
```

I've blacklisted the floppy drive and I also disabled the floppy drive in vSphere. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Did you disable the Floppy drive in the VM's 'firmware' level?  Otherwise it'll stil 'see' a floppy drive whether it exists or not in the VM.  This is more or less how the BIOS reveals to the underlying system whether a device exists or not, and this `fd0` problem is one I run into *regularly* on my VMs in VMware (I always boot to firmware and disable the floppy drive on first-run)

Comment: This is happening to me too, I tried to comment out `/dev/fd0` from /etc/fstab with no luck.

Answer (score 9):

If you have removed your swap file then ensure that in step 3 that you have commented out the swap file line (it will have 'swap' in the same line) and in step 4 comment out the first (and only)

1. Run this `dpkg-reconfigure initramfs-tools` and then restart and continue
2. `lsblk -f` command, and note the UUID's
3. Ensure that the UUID's in this file are right `/etc/fstab` -- `sudo nano /etc/fstab`
4. Ensure that the UUID's in this file are also right `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume.` -- `sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume.`
5. Run `sudo update-initramfs -u` and restart

Sources:

https://tinycp.com/community/show/solved-print-req-error-i-o-error-dev-fd0-sector-0,43.html#sidebar

https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2017/09/msg00866.html

Answer (score 6):

I saw this on the following website: https://tinycp.com/community/show/solved-print-req-error-i-o-error-dev-fd0-sector-0,43.html

```
# rmmod floppy
# echo "blacklist floppy" | tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-floppy.conf 
# dpkg-reconfigure initramfs-tools
```

For me this seems to work pretty fine!
(Oh, I just saw the page was referenced already in an earlier anwer. But this containts step-by-step commands (as does the linked page) which solved the issue for me.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why are you disabling the Floppy Drive? Why not just remove it from the VM's configuration?

I completely removed the Floppy Drive from the configuration of the VM.  Time will tell if the error returns.

Comment: That's a problem in VMware. If I remove the floppy in the ESXi 6.7 web interface, it reappears. I don't see the floppy in vCenter at all, I cannot remove or add it.

Answer (score 1):

This did not work on our 18.04 server, using tee gave permission denied to create the file. This however worked:

```
sudo rmmod floppy
sudo sh -c "echo 'blacklist floppy' >  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-floppy.conf"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure initramfs-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting this error, which made me boot into emergency mode and did not allow SSH/remote access.

I removed all custom /etc/fstab entries except the default ones. In my case I had entries to mount hard disks that were no longer plugged in, once I removed them I stopped getting that error. For reference, my error said the problem was with sr0, but I couldn't find a reference to sr0 in any logs/fdisk.

Answer (score 0):

You can see my answer here: [I encountered the print_req_error while trying to open Ubuntu 16.04 on my dual booted HP laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108310/i-encountered-the-print-req-error-while-trying-to-open-ubuntu-16-04-on-my-dual-b)

As I used to encounter the same problem.