# I encountered the print_req_error while trying to open Ubuntu 16.04 on my dual booted HP laptop

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, hard-drive, busybox

So I have an HP Pavilion 15au627tx laptop and I had been using Ubuntu  16.04 for about 6 months before I first encountered this problem. Once when I logged in last November, everything was in a read only mode and I freaked out but nothing I tried seemed to work. I shut down my computer and Ubuntu never seemed to open, I seemed to get the BusyBox error. However as I had very little time to focus on that, I used Windows which worked perfectly fine. However, now that I have been trying to fix it, nothing seems to work. I tried fixing it but nothing seemed to work and eached time I went onto Ubuntu I got a huge list of corrupted sectors which made no sense to me. I finally decided to backup my data from Windows and decided to wipe the Ubuntu partition, and tried reinstalling. I installed it alongside windows using the same partition as before. However it didn't work and each time I've tried to log in, this thing comes on the screen. I'm really confused about this as I don't know what this means. All questions seemingly related to this state that my hard disk is dying. However, I've been working with Windows to do class work  and it seems perfectly fine. How do I fix this? Do I replace the hard disk (I have an extended warranty on my laptop)? Is there any other way to fix it without any such drastic measures. Here's  a screenshot if you want to know what I see https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZZfJ.jpg
Also, it may or may not be relevant but I had to reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 twice before. Once when I downgraded from 18.04 to 16.04 and then the OS didnt work , reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 once again and things seemed perfectly fine. In case you want to know who the hard drive manufacturer is, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering no one answered this, I would just like to add that reinstalling it does the trick. I tried 18.04 once again and it seems fine.
Edit: After a few months, this still happens with me, so I might reccommend changing hard drive.